# Automating Posting of XML payload via HTTP API restful-url

Tags: xml, powershell, postman, restful-url

I'm new to API integrations  and currently using Postman UI to manually post XML payload body to a suppliers API webservice. This works well however I need to find a solution to automate this process.

The idea is that our app will generate an XML output file to a directory and an scheduled script or app read/ wrap the  contents of the XML into the body of a HTTP API POST. After processing the  XML file needs to be moved to an archived folder for audit purposes.

Ideally the script or app will then be able to write this POST response to a text file (for audit purposes).

Can anyone recommend any PowerShell script templates or alternative approaches that will be able to automate this process without extensive coding knowledge?

The environment is Windows.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Postman creates  perfect eco system for API development. It allows you to manually play around with API, automate it , monitor it , mock it etc.

You don't need a separate tool for your use case, you can create a collection and pass the request body as a variable

set request body as :

```
{{testBody}}
```

[image]

Now export the collection as json and run it using newman from powershell

```
 $xmlFile = Get-Content .\test.xml
 $a = "run .\canvasjs.postman_collection.json  --env-var=`"testBody=$xmlFile`" -r htmlextra"
 Start-Process "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\newman" -args $a
```

Comment: Hi, 
Many thanks for your reply. 

I cannot workout how to get this parameter to work --env-var=`"testBody=$xmlFile`" 

Do I need to configure anything in the collection in Postman before exporting to .json file?
Not sure where to define this variable {{testBody}}

Apologies as not very familiar with Postman - tried Googling and couldn't find the answer 

thanks again!

Comment: @JohnSmith added the screenshot

Comment: Hi @PDHide, thanks for the screenshot. Can you advise why I might need receiving any results back when I execute the Powershell? See screenshot https://ibb.co/yN5PmN0

Comment: is the new cmd opens up ? the htmlextra report is not installed ?

Comment: npm install -g newman,newman-reporter-htmlextra

Comment: I tried executing this command  as admin powershell npm install -g newman,newman-reporter-htmlextra and getting this error npm ERR! Invalid tag name "newman,newman-reporter-htmlextra": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes.

So I Googled and found this command npm install -g newman-reporter-htmlextra, this appeared to install, however when I execute your script again a box quickly pops up and disappears. I have tried a fresh install on another Windows 10 pc and same issue. Is it possible to write the results to a file instead?